# Find right moment to access DOM elements created from data from asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I have a list of items created from data from an asynchronous call and I want to scroll to a particular element. Therefore I need to access DOM after it is ready.

I tried the following solution:

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div id='scrollableDiv'>
      <p v-for='item in items' :id='item.id'>{{item.title}}</p>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  async created () {
    response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
    this.items = response.data
    const selectedElement = document.getElementById('5')
    this.scrollTo(selectedElement)
  },
  data: () => ({
      items: [] 
    }),
  methods: {
    scrollTo (selectedElement) {
       const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById('scrollableDiv')
       scrollableDiv.scrollTop = selectedElement.offsetTop
    }
  }
})
```

This does not work, because `document.getElementById('5')` is called before DOM is ready.

How to execute `document.getElementById('5')` when the DOM is ready and the element with ID '5' exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you update `this.items` from the response, you need to give Vue a chance to recognize the change and update the DOM accordingly

```
this.items = response.data
await this.$nextTick()
const selectedElement = document.getElementById('5')
```

or the equivalent using callbacks